# Disable autoconfiguration of new network interface on Linux desktop

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ipv4

I am running Ubuntu Linux (desktop) and whenever I insert an external network card to my computer, it automatically creates a new interface (that is okay) but also instantly giving the interface an IP address.

Is there any possibility to stop that behaviour? So that no IP address is assigned but the interface is created?

I thought about something like: `sysctl` and `net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 1` but for IPv4 (or even for a single interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you telling about [Link-Local Addresses](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3927.txt). try to shut down avahi daemon to disabling it.